# Add a new property to each object in a collection

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Can you help me simplify the way I add new property to an array of objects

I have an object like this,

```
response.data = [ {'year':2015, 'month':1},
                  {'year':'2016','month':2}
];
```

and I want to add a new property 'monthName'

```
response.data = [{'year':2015, 'month':1,'monthName':'January'},
                 {'year':'2016','month':2,'monthName':'February'}
];
```

This is what i did,

```
 var data = response.data;    // Improvement
 var ctr = 0;
 $.each(response.data, function(a,b){
         data[ctr].monthName = monthNumberToName(b.month);
         ctr++;
 });

 return data;
```

Can you help me simplify my code, thank you!

Comment: Your loop is bad implementation. `data[ctr]` is equal to `b`. `ctr` is same as `a`. `$.each`'s syntax is `(index, item)`. You should directly use it. You can also use `Array.map` but its signature is different. You can do `response.data.map(function(obj){ obj.monthName = monthNumberToName(b.month); return obj; })`

Comment: Does your code work already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map` to make your code look shorter and manageable:

```js
var response = {};
response.data = [ 
   {'year':2015, 'month':1},
   {'year':'2016','month':2}
]; 
var data = response.data;

data.map((item)=>{
   item.monthName =  monthNumberToName(item.month);
});

function monthNumberToName(monthNumber){
   if(monthNumber == 1){
     return "January";
   }
   if(monthNumber == 2){
     return "February";
   }
}

console.log(response.data);
```

Comment: Your `monthNumberToName` can be improved a lot

Comment: That is just a sample code which is simply an assumption. OP asks for improvement in assigning `monthName` and not `monthNumberToName` so i have `monthNumberToName` as a sample code.

Answer (score 1):

Simpler version could be

```
return response.data.map( s => Object.assign( {}, s, { monthName : monthNumberToName( s.month) } );
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `forEach` and its first parameter:

```js
const data = response.data;
data.forEach(d => d.monthName = monthNumberToName(d.month));
return data;
```

Comment: Does `forEach` return anything? As far as I know, it doesn't

Comment: Your updated code can be further reduced if you use `.map`. Please remember, there are functions specific to operation.

Answer (score 1):

```
function addProp(){
   var data = res.data;   
    $.each(res.data, function(a,b){
         //b is object and //a is the index
         b.monthName = monthNumberToName(b.month);
    });
  return data;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var monthNames = [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June","July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ];

var response = {};
response.data = [ 
  {'year':2015, 'month':1},
  {'year':'2016','month':2}
]; 

response.data.map((item,key)=>{
item.monthName =  monthNames[key];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you can try this.

```
const months = [
  'January',
  'February',
  'March',
  'April',
  'May',
  'June',
  'July',
  'August',
  'Septemper',
  'October',
  'November',
  'December'
]

var data = [
  {'year':2015, 'month':1},
  {'year':'2016','month':2}
]

data = data.map(m=> {
  m['monthName'] = months[m.month - 1]
  return m
})

console.log(data)
```

Answer (score -1):

[Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#forEach) greatly helps in simplifying the code.

You can do it like this:

Maintain an array of months:

```
const months = ["Jan","Feb", "Mar"];

let data = [ {'year':2015, 'month':1},
    {'year':'2016','month':2}
];

_.forEach(data, function(value, key) {
  value["monthName"] = months[value.month - 1];
});
```